# Adding fade-in effect li:hover with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, fadein

I'm coding a new theme in WordPress, and I want to display more animated pages than the old interface.

I want to add some effect (i.e a fade-in effect) to my `li:hover` element. How can I do this ?

Here is my CSS:

```
/*Videos*/
.PozVideos {float:left;width:940px;min-height:155px;margin:0px 0px 20px 0px;}
.PozVideos .Caption {float:left;width:930px;padding:0px 0px 10px 10px;margin-bottom:8px;border-bottom:1px solid #F8F8E6;height:25px;line-height:33px;font-size:14px;color:#fff;overflow: hidden;}
.PozVideos ul {padding:0px;margin:0px 0px 5px 7px;}
.PozVideos ul li {float:left;width:150px;height:100px;margin-right:5px;background:#F8F8E6;text-align:center;}
.PozVideos ul li img {float:left;width:140px;border:none;height:90px;padding:5px;}
.PozVideos ul li:hover {float:left;opacity:0.7;filter:alpha(opacity=70); /* For IE8 and earlier */}
.PozVideos .Title {float:left;margin:-35px 0px 0px 0px;width:150px;height:30px;line-height:15px;}
.TransationsImages {opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */}
.TransationsImagesHover {opacity:0.7;filter:alpha(opacity=70); /* For IE8 and earlier */}
.TransationsTitle {opacity:0.9;filter:alpha(opacity=0.9); /* For IE8 and earlier */}

.Pozn-img-play {
    background:transparent;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
    border:0px;

}

.Pozn-img-play:hover {
    background:url('img/play.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!--Videos-->
<div class="PozVideos BgPurple RadiusTopTen">
    <div class="Caption">Video Galeri</div>
    <ul>
        <li><div class="PotImage"><a href=""><img src="assets/demo/video.jpg" alt=""></a><div class="Pozn-img-play"></div></div></li>
        <li><div class="PotImage"><a href=""><img src="assets/demo/video.jpg" alt=""></a></div></li>
        <li><div class="PotImage"><a href=""><img src="assets/demo/video.jpg" alt=""></a></div></li>
        <li><div class="PotImage"><a href=""><img src="assets/demo/video.jpg" alt=""></a></div></li>
        <li><div class="PotImage"><a href=""><img src="assets/demo/video.jpg" alt=""></a></div></li>
        <li><div class="PotImage"><a href=""><img src="assets/demo/video.jpg" alt=""></a></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!--Videos-->
```

Comment: actually i am new for jquery couldt do anything. just want to display play icon with some animation (.Pozn-img-play) for li hover

Comment: Also Thank you so much @David, i start learning English with you too.. (: (I am a Turkish so my English is not really well..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this CSS:

```
 .Pozn-img-play {
        background:transparent;
        position:relative;
        z-index:1;
        cursor:pointer;
        width:150px;
        height:100px;
        border:0px;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
       -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;

    }

    .Pozn-img-play:hover {
        background:url('img/play.png') no-repeat center center;
        opacity: 0.1;
    }​
```

Comment: thank you , but is this ok for IE Browser ? I think jquery effect method is better than CSS 3 transition methots ?

Comment: @FatihToprak try fiddle i mentioned in ans. It does not use CSS3 transitions though they are really cool and all but not very well supported in old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phazorrise/u4kCR/) . You can make this effect more smooth if you use jQuery instead of just css.

You can either use `fadeIn`, `fadeOut`. One advantage of using jQuery instead of CSS3 is you gain good browser compatibility.